# "binascii.Error: decoding with 'hex' codec failed (Error: Odd-length string)" error

Tags: python, bitcoin

```
import codecs
import random

private_key = random.randrange(1,115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936)

private_key = hex(private_key)[2:]

private_key_bytes = codecs.decode(private_key, 'hex')
```

I'm assuming 2<sup>256</sup> is the upper bound for possible Bitcoin private key. Right? Even though when I actually manually go past that upper limit it still works. But that's unrelated to my issue.

This is a small piece of the code. About 90% of the time it works and I'm able to proceed with the final code, but then at times it gives me the error "binascii.Error: Odd-length string". What's causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The private key can be an odd-length string, as `hex()` will exclude leading zeros from its output (if they exist).

To resolve, pad the private key with enough zeros to make it 64 characters.

```py
import codecs
import random

private_key = random.randrange(1, 2**256)
private_key = '0' * (len(hex(private_key)) % 2) + hex(private_key)[2:]

private_key_bytes = codecs.decode(private_key, 'hex')
```

Comment: Somewhat simpler solution: `private_key = f'{private_key:064x}'`. The `x` converts to hex (without adding a `0x` you need to strip off later), and the `064` aligns it to a 64 wide field with automatic zero padding. The OP should know this won't be securely generated though (much better than what you'd get from plain C, as Python does initialize the PRNG for you with system provided randomness, so it's probably going to be okay if you don't publish a stream of outputs from it, but may as well go for theoretically secure too).

Answer (score 0):

It is because `hex()` does not include leading zeros.

Either way, you shouldn't use a PRNG for a private key, please use Python's [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_hex) module:

```
>>> import secrets
>>> secrets.token_hex(256)
'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'
```

From [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#module-random):

> The pseudo-random generators of this module should not be used for
> security purposes. For security or cryptographic uses, see the [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_hex)
> module.

Answer (score 0):

Many integers will produce an odd number of hex bytes. For a smaller example, consider generating numbers in `range(256)`. If you randomly generate 16-255 (`0x10` to `0xff`) you'll trim it to two digits, corresponding to one real byte of data. But if you generate 15, `hex` will return `'0xf'`, and `'f'` that can't decode unambiguously to a single byte (did you want `b'\x0f'` or `b'\xf0'`?).

Really, if you want to generate the bytes of a private key, the easy solution is to just generate the bytes directly, and use a secure means of generating the bytes (Python's PRNG is not suitable for cryptographically secure random numbers):

```
import os

private_key_bytes = os.urandom(32)  # Directly pulls 32 bytes/256 bits of cryptographically secure
                                    # random bytes from OS source
private_key = int.from_bytes(private_key_bytes, 'big')  # If needed
```

Or equivalently using the `random` module as a wrapper for `os.urandom`:

```
import random

private_key_bytes = random.SystemRandom().randbytes(32)  # SystemRandom directly wraps os.urandom
# Conversion to int unchanged
```

[The `secrets` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) provides similar wrapper functionality with cryptographically secure random number generation and while it was only introduced in 3.6, you should be able to rely on that in most contexts, making for a third option:

```
import secrets

private_key_bytes = secrets.token_bytes(32)
```

Comment: To be clear, all three options here are really the same option, some are just a little more clear about intent than others.